# Refresh installshield basicMsi UI after custom action

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, installshield

As the title suggests im trying to update the basicMsi UI in response to a c# custom action that is being run. I have tried all the suggestions that Michael Urman has suggested in other posts but i still cant get this to work.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43465413/how-to-refresh-wizard-ui-on-the-wizard-in-installshield)

- Installshield 2023 Premier
- c# unmanaged custom action using the Wix [CustomAction]

I have a dialog that is trying to activate a license key over an http endpoint. I have this working and the custom action will return ActionResult.Success or ActionResult.Failure based on my endpoint. This all works fine.

This all happens with an 'Activate' button in the UI dialog that takes the users license key input. Once the http call completes i want to update the UI with any possible failure messages from the http endpoint. As well as if its a successful call, then i want to enable the 'Next' button in the dialog and now disable the 'Activate' button since its no longer needed.

All these custom actions are do via a DoAction even on the 'Activate' button click. I can't for the life of me figure out how to update the text and Next button states after a CA has completed its execution. They never update in real time. The only way i can see the changes is to click back, to move out of the current dialog, and then move next to get back to the activate dialog. Then i can see the changes because the dialog reloads with the previously set properties. HOW CAN THIS BE UPDATED REAL TIME WITOU HAVING TO MOVE BETWEEN DIALOGS? This seems like a pretty important use case for decades now, why is this not a simple task?!?

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of windows installer.  The workaround is to create a second dialog that looks like the first dialog and transition to it.